# He should "be wearing"/"wear" a helmet

Tags: modal-verbs, infinitives

I don't understand the difference between "be wearing" and "wear".

For example:

> 1. He should be wearing a helmet.
> 2. He should wear a helmet.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: The first construction is used exclusively when the moment for wearing a helmet is *now*, and the guy isn't. For example, if a guy on a motorcycle passes you on the highway, without a helmet, you would say, right at that time, "*he should be wearing a helmet* [right now]". You could also say "*he should wear a helmet*", but in that case you're recommending he make a habit of helmet use, beyond just commenting on his current condition. You could also say "*he should wear a helmet*" to suggest he put one on *in the future*.

Comment: There are other uses. "He should be wearing a helmet by this time tomorrow." "He'll be on the steps in front of St. Paul's tomorrow. He should be wearing a helmet, so you'll have no trouble recognizing him." Etc.

Comment: This is a question?

Comment: @DanBron why not post your comment as an answer? I think it's spot-on.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I feel like a fraud because I can't explain it in linguistic terms. I mean, I could try, but I'd embarrass myself and confuse OP.

Comment: @DanBron, that hasn't stopped me yet! ;-)

Comment: @DanBron, If you don't, some other fraud, such as me, may come along and do it for you ;)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan That's ok by me! And if you or anyone else wants to post an answer based on my comments, he has my unqualified permission. No need to even mention me.

Comment: Nah - too much bad personal karma if I do that.  I'm also trying to get you to post your answer is it covers the question well.

Answer (score 3):

1 refers to the current state of affairs; 2 refers to the future.

1. Good grief. John has just left on his motorcycle and he's forgotten his helmet. He **should be wearing** his helmet!
2. John is about to leave on his motorbike. Tell him **he should wear** his helmet.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with tkp's overly generalized answer provided above, as #2 does not necessarily imply a recommendation about the future.  Rather, #2 should be viewed as a generalized recommendation that covers both the present and future.

Also, #1 could take place in the future, but most likely takes place in the present tense.  An example of usage reflecting a future event would be, "He should be wearing a helmet when he arrives."

To answer your question directly, both sentences are grammatically correct. The difference between them is that while #2 presents a generalized recommendation that may or may not focus on a particular event, #1 could be any of the following:

- An explanation of what "he" is assumed to be doing (e.g. "he told me he is wearing a helmet, so I trust that he is")
- A recommendation as to what "he" should be doing (e.g. "he should wear a helmet")
- A guess as to what "he" is doing (e.g. "I don't know if he's wearing a helmet, but I would guess that he is")

Thus #1 is potentially far more robust, but also potentially far more ambiguous without context.

Answer (score 0):

Be wearing:

> Come on, jacob just left to go skiing without his helmet. He should be wearing his helmet!

Wear:

> Jacob’s about to leave, go tell him to wear his helmet.